# In NSIS, How do I create a custom page containing an image?

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to add a custom page to an NSIS installation, that will contain a title and an image.
I'm using Modern UI.
Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the nsDialogs plugin to create custom pages, it has [helper macros to load bitmaps](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#mref-setimage) and icons...

Comment: Thanks. the [nsDialogs Documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) shows it very clear. Thank you